# jQuery .load() XHTML issue

Tags: jquery, xhtml, load

I am having some strange problems loading content from another XHTML page via jQuery. When the second page I try to load from is served as XHTML I get the below error. I don't know if it helps but both documents validate when I get the error.

> Uncaught Error:
>   NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: DOM
>   Exception 7

Currently the header on the second page I load from is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <meta name="language" content="en" />  
 <title>some title</title>
 <!-- CSS & Javascript included here -->
</head>
```

The content type is set as:

> application/xhtml+xml;charset=iso-8859-1

**Interestingly, when I remove all the XHTML stuff from the header and stop setting the content type the error does not occur and everything works great**.

The load process currently looks like the below. It works fine when everything is plain HTML.

```
$('#overpage').find(".wrap").load(this.getTrigger().attr("href")+" #op").show();
```

I'm curious why the process only does not work when the second page I load from is XHTML. I don't want to serve the page as just plain HTML and am looking for advice on what I am doing wrong. Both pages validate and I'm really scratching my head here. Many thanks!

Comment: @Urfe what browser are you getting the error in?

Comment: The error I posted is from Chrome. Firefox fails too. Firebug gives me a really long error that starts: 

"uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsIDOMNSHTMLElement.innerHTML]"

Comment: Hmmm... according to some pages I've found (http://fitzsimmons.ca/jquery-xhtml-11-strict-and-ns_error_invalid_pointer/) this error is related to having bad markup. This is confusing to me as both pages pass validation when I test them. :(

Comment: Try removing the `<!DOCTYPE` rule as a simple test. If that works, then it's something related to the `XHTML 1.1 Strict` you are imposing, which is broken somewhere in the page.

Comment: When I removed the <!DOCTYPE rule it worked. Since the page validates with it I'm not too sure where the problem is. I'll try to look for the possible breaking point. I may just end up changing the doc type on these pages.

Comment: Interestingly everything works perfectly in Opera with no errors. I went through the entire page (it's short) and checked all the tags by hand. It's fairly simple and everything seems fine. Since the page validates, I can't find any problems, and it will only be fully seen when Javascript is disabled I'm just going to bite the bullet and serve it as plain HTML. I really wish I knew what was going on here but this is clearly beyond me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is related to the fact that document.write does not work with XHTML strict:

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue a bit back, I think it's caused because jquery takes the (X)HTML it gets, inserts it into a dummy div, and only then runs the selector (#op in your case) to retrieve the correct part and insert that into the final place. Here's the relevant jquery code (taken from 1.5.1, but 1.6 looks identical):

```
jQuery("<div>")
    // inject the contents of the document in, removing the scripts
    // to avoid any 'Permission Denied' errors in IE
    .append(responseText.replace(rscript, ""))

    // Locate the specified elements
    .find(selector)
```

In Firebug, I can see that it errors out on the .append line, because it doesn't grok a `<?xml` or `<DOCTYPE` header inside a div... So I guess this is just something jquery doesn't support, not sure how this could be fixed in a sane manner.

Answer (score 1):

XHTML does not support document.write or innerHTML. Due to the fact, that jQuery inserts the new code using one of these methods, all XHTML compatible browsers will error out.

XHTML with application/xhtml+xml does not support raw modification of the source using any of these jQuery methods: append(), html(), insert...(), etc.

Instead, query for some JSON data and insert the AJAX-received values into either pre-defined tags using .text() / .val() or dynamically create those nodes using document.createElement('someTag').